# How do I use registers and offset addresses?

Tags: c++, memory, driver, cpu-registers, gpio

Currently, I am trying to write a GPIO driver and attempting to wrap my head around a couple of things. After searching the internet, I haven't really found a clear answer to a few questions I have regarding base addresses, registers, and offset addresses.

For the questions below, lets say I have an arbitrary register D1:F0 and an offset address of 10h-13h (32 bits in size). Bit 0 is always 1 and reserved, bits 10:1 is the GPIO base address, and bits 31:11 are reserved and always 0. This register has a default value of 00000001h. Using this information:

1) What is Function Number-to-Root Port Mapping in regards to D1:F0?

2) Does D1:F0 contain a port that would be usable in code?

3) How does the offset address relate to question 1/question 2?

4) The default value of the register has all bits off except the first reserved bit (which should be 1), correct?

Paranoia Check Question: Bits[4:1] means bits 1-4, right?

Thanks in advance guys and gals!

Note: I need to point out that all data, registers, memory addresses, and offsets in this post are arbitrary and in no way reflect data I will be working with/have access to. This is just conceptual and to illustrate a point.

Answer (score 2):

After researching, I've found a few things out:

1) Function Number-to-Root Port Mapping in regards to the example of **D1:F0** is a notation that means that the register is on **D**evice **1**, **F**unction **0** in regards to the PCH and Bus. A bus device can have multiple "functions" that, for example, could be used by different peripherals.

2) Yes and no. NRP notation gives you, for lack of a better term, a logical mapping of the Bus Device to a function and masks the actual hexadecimal base address and offsets for the register. Processor/Chipset documentation has the physical addresses of where the bus starts, and relates those addresses to NRP notation.

3) The offset address does not relate to the example NRP notation of **D1:F0**. **D1:F0** is just a representation of the base address for the register in regards to the Bus, not an actual register address. You would apply the offset (or offset range) to the base address of the register.

4) Correct.Just used a bit field to verify and wrote it out on paper to verify.

Extra Question: The notation of **[Number1:Number2]** in regards to bits means bits **Number1** through **Number2** , reading bits from left to right (High Order to Low Order bit). So, for example, **bits [15:4]** means **bits 4 through 15** for a total of 12 bits.